# Why can't I write "<?PHP" tag when I'm starting PHP in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm trying `PHP` in `VSCode`, but when I typed

```
<?PHP
 echo ("Something")
?>
```

the opening and closing PHP tag colored red, usually which means something is in `**error**`, I guess, although there is no error message shown.

I've already installed `XAMPP` in `D:\XAMPP` and run the server.

I've also already customized the setting and also changed *Environment Variable* by adding path `D:\XAMPP` as suggested by Stackoverflow community.

My PHP extensions are:

1. Open PHP/HTML/JS in Browser
2. PHP Extension Pack
3. PHP File Types
4. PHP Intelephense
5. PHP Project

The customized setting:

```
    "php.executablePath": "D:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "D:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

Here is what displayed by Chrome:

```
<?php
    echo("Something");
?>
```

which I expected it would display:

```
Something
```

and not the code.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code. But it may not like caps - I know I don't ..

Comment: also worth noting that it may be flagging the missing semi-colon. It's perfectly valid here, but IMO it's better to add it in.. much better to play it safe than save one char

Comment: My money's on the uppercase `<?PHP`

Comment: Have you actually started the Apache service in XAMPP control panel? And does the file have a `.php` extension?

Comment: To your first problem regarding red color: Are you sure that your color settings are not simply defining them to show in red color? **EDIT**: Can you maybe add a screenshot of the colored `<?php`?

Comment: To your second problem regarding what is displayed by chrome: Have you actually opened the file via a webserver or did you just enter the path i.e file:/// ....?

Comment: @j08691 As I stated under a deleted answer, an uppercase `<?php` is working just fine including long EOL versions. An example of it working including EOL: https://3v4l.org/OCkZ4 (of course it might be that theres a vscode bug in here and it *thinks* that its invalid but it isn't)

Comment: @treyBake Eureka! I've found the solution: When I chose "PHP Server" at Output Terminal, I got info about the localhost address, and I tried it and works perfectly well. Caps doesn't have any problem with it, I've tried it.

Comment: @Sam Yups, Apache service is running well. Probably I got wrong in using localhost address which I should type completely as suggested by Output terminal such as "localhost:3000"

Comment: No, localhost will serve at port `:80` by default unless you've manually changed it. As long as it's on port 80 you don't need to explicitly type the port.

Comment: @Xatenev After I tried to evaluate, then I changed the Theme Color of VSCode, and it change to other color too.. So the red previously didn't mean failure.  I think failure is marked by red underline or something, as I ever got it when I test PHP programming before I install XAMPP.

Comment: @Sam, the output terminal window say it:
"PHP server running with d:\Data Programming\Visual Code Studio\ as root directory. Reach server using localhost:3000"

I don't remember if I ever changed it, but you probably right.

Comment: It sounds like you have another web server running as well as xampp?

Comment: @Xatenev, answering about your suggestion for my second problem:
Before I just typed: http://localhost/php/test.php, it displayed Error 404.
Then I typed: http://localhost:3000/php/test.php

It's solved. Thank you all, guys!!

Comment: You must already have another web server running that you've installed then - xampp doesn't server on port 3000 unless you've specified that port in the config files.

Comment: @Sam I assume one of the plugins, probably the "PHP Project" plugin start the native PHP webserver. **EDIT**: Yes it does https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FrogTheFrog.php-project - from the extension settings listed: `(Default: ["-S", "localhost:3000"])`

Comment: @Xatenev nah all the plugin does is open the file in the browser, essentially a shortcut to the "localhost" URL - there isn't a native PHP web server in Windows environments so either OP has mis-configured xampp, or has installed more than one apache web server and the other is using port 3000 instead... it's working for OP which is great, but the question is essentially a configuration issue - not a development issue.

Comment: @Sam Did you see my comment edit? - Of course there is a native PHP web server in windows environments. `php -S` and it works just fine: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: @Xatenev and if you look at the requirements for that plugin, it needs a PHP server to be installed already.... because there is no native PHP in windows, that's why you have to point VS Code at your PHP exe in the user settings. Apache web servers are typically Linux/UNIX based, Windows uses IIS by default which is why WAMP or XAMPP is required for PHP development on Windows. Anyway - that's not the point of the question... the plugin that OP used isn't required and is serving the file on a different port - so it's a config issue, still not a development issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible issues based on what you're describing:

1. Check the Apache service is actually started in the XAMPP control panel, it should be green and no error messages being output.
2. Check your file has a `.php` extension, the web server won't know to pre-process it otherwise.
3. Check you're actually serving the file through the web server. If your file is called `foobar.php` it should be located in `D:\xampp\htdocs\` and then navigate to `http://localhost/foobar.php` in your browser.
4. Check your `HOSTS` file to make sure you don't have some strange redirect rule for `localhost` going on. (`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` **make a backup first, especially if you're unsure how to edit this file**)